# how to set width of truncate lines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm aware of auto-fill in emacs, this is great and I use it when I want text to have a line break at a particular width (e.g. when coding). However, when editing and reading text I don't want to reformat the text (`M-q`) and insert line breaks as this then looks odd when exporting the text e.g. to an email or Microsoft Word.

Is emacs 'truncate lines' the tool for the job? Seems to be but I can't figure out how to set the width for truncate lines, it seems to only be able to truncate at the screen width - is there a setting for this or another mode?

(I'm using spacemacs, but this shouldn't have much relevance)

Comment: Are you not just looking for `visual-line-mode`?

Comment: i'm looking for a visual-line-mode where one can set the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a code addressing truncating a buffer less than the wincow's wicth in the emacs exchange [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/truncate-lines-at-a-specific-visual-column-instead-of-truncating-in-the-last-vis#21025).
Look at @JeanPierre answer. It uses `set-window-margins` see the emacs manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html#Display-Margins).

It is an interactive function, so use `M-x my/change-window-width` to call it after evaluating in scratch.

```
(defun my/change-window-width (width)
"Adjust margins so that window is centered"
  (interactive "NWindow width: ")
  (if (= 0 width)
      (set-window-margins nil 0 0)
    (let* ((cur-width (window-width))
           (cur-m (window-margins))
           (cur-l (if (and cur-m (car cur-m)) (car cur-m) 0))
           (cur-r (if (and cur-m (cdr cur-m)) (cdr cur-m) 0))
           (lr (- (+ cur-l cur-r cur-width) width))
           (left (/ lr 2))
           (right (if (= 0 (% lr 2)) left (1+ left))))
      (set-window-margins nil (max left 0) (max right 0)))))
```

It is a variation of a function in `visual-line-mode` see doc [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode)

To truncate only a part of the buffer, it looks like fill-column

Comment: btw do you post anywhere about your flamenco guitar building and python coding? sounds interesting from my point of view in a cube farm ;)

Comment: @chris Not anymore I don't.... Might get back to if I get some order into my life. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I generally use

```
M 72 M-x set-fill-column
```

which breaks the lines at 72 columns. That's still going to get in the way of your "don't muck up import to Word" issue, though. If you save your file with a particular format (eg, by using `M-x xml-mode`) then I believe that would help you with the import issue.

Comment: thanks, but the autofill was something I was trying to avoid. In other editors I have used there has been a 'virtual linebreak' mode for the very reason of viewing textual content in a nice way (no long lines to scan) without inserting line breaks in the doc.